# Pass variable name in Jenkins Vault secrets path

Tags: jenkins, hashicorp-vault

I am not able to pass ${environment} in the vault secret path for reading the values.
May be secret getting initialized before variables are getting set.
Kindly help as I'm not able to read environment-specific values from the same vault repo.
[image]

Comment: Where is `environment` defined?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I am passing it as a parameter to the build.

Comment: Did you try accessing it within the `params` object already?

Comment: I created a Choice parameter called environment with values qa and stage in the build config. While starting the build I am selecting the value.

Answer (score 0):

It worked pretty nicely for me using a choice parameter in a parameterized build. I think your issue is in the used Vault path (vault/secret/$environment). I think the correct in your case is just "secret/$environment". Does your secret engine start with "vault"?

Just FYI, if you define the variable in "Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Environment variables" it'll work too.

Comment: My build is a parameterized build and I am trying to pass the parameter to the Vault secrets path.

Comment: There's something wrong with your Vault path. I updated the answer.

Comment: No, for privacy I have given a dummy path in the above screenshot. Our Vault doesn't start with Vault. I tried replacing {} braces but still no luck. In the below error, I replaced the original path with dummy path.

com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.exception.VaultPluginException: could not read from vault: Vault responded with HTTP status code: 404
Response body: {"errors":[]}
 at path: secret/$environment
 at com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.VaultAccessor.read(VaultAccessor.java:36)

Comment: Are you using the latest Jenkins/plugin version? I have Jenkins 2.346.3 and Vault plugin 356.ved18810a_b_828.

Comment: We are using Jenkins ver. 2.150.2 and HashiCorp Vault plugin ver. 2.2.0

Comment: The Vault plugin 2.2.0 is really old, it is worth trying a newer version (https://plugins.jenkins.io/hashicorp-vault-plugin/#releases).

Comment: Sure @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira i will try that. Thank you for your help.